Eas build failed on expo app on expo sdk 50?
Build failed: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.
why did it faill how to trace it I don't know how to check the issue
it was working last 2 months ago I did not change anything on configuration just updated some libraries and ui change

hello sir, Did you found the reason why?
